# fp_evm::GenesisAccount causes StakingElection.fail

Tags: staking, evm, session, election, npos

As the title says, I have added EVM Compatibility to my NPoS runtime(using [chainsafe/substrate-node-template](https://github.com/ChainSafe/substrate-node-template/tree/dfo/gssmr-test-staking)), and when i run my node with Alice and Bob validators, the StakingElection begins to fail.

**NOTE** The chainsafe template had an issue where eras didn't change hence no election occured, but I have solved that with [this pr](https://github.com/ChainSafe/substrate-node-template/pull/4), the NPoS election works fine not having added the EVM pallet.

[image]

**UPDATE 1** I have added pallet_ethereum, changed SubstrateBlockHashMapping to EthereuBlockhashMapping, still the same issue.
If I remove all EVM related stuff, my NPoS works fine. Solution is submitted, election is finalized and a new authority set is chosen.

**UPDATE 2**
I forgot to add an image of whaat should normally happen(when pallet_evm is not installed)
[image]

**UPDATE 3**
Here is the branch and repo in question [here](https://github.com/talhadaar/chainsafe-substrate-node-template/tree/question)

**UPDATE 4**
It appears using fp_evm::GenesisAccount to create and endow some test accounts in chain_spec for EVMConfig breaks the NPoS election for both polkadotv0.9.22 and polkadotv0.9.25, without endowed test accounts I cannot test any of the EVM compatibility.

**UPDATE 5**
I have added 5 accounts in EVMGenesis config, but looks there aren't any
[image]

**UPDATE 6**
In the block where StakingElection fails, logs show there are 2 consensus engines.
[image]

**LATEST UPDATE**
Hey guys! I have figured out how to look at node's logs, and here are the results. Can someone please help?
[image: terminal logs]

[image: explorer logs]

Comment: Can you provide more detail on what the failure mode is and what debug logs are? https://docs.substrate.io/main-docs/test/debug/

Comment: Im not sure how you mean. Are there particular details i should share? Im new to substrate still

Comment: Updated comment. Please provide verbose logs to diagnose what he failure mode is

Comment: I'm not writing any logic at the moment, so not sure where to place the log statements. I'm just trying to add the pallet_evm to my runtime but it just breaks the election.

Comment: Are you using `pallet-ethereum` preset in [frontier](https://github.com/paritytech/frontier/tree/master/frame) ? That pallet seems to require primitives and depend other pallets that I don't know if you might have not included. Worth the check.

Comment: No only adding pallet-evm from frontier for now and integrating it in the runtime

Comment: I have updated the question with link to the repo/branch being used @DanShields

Comment: @MuhammadTalhaDar i am also trying to add EVM_Pallet in my runtime can you tell me which version of rust you have used and which branch of substrate you have used i also want to integrate evm pallet in NPOS.

Comment: polkadot v0.9.22 with nightly rust toolchain